# Does Fermat's Theorem for Stationary Points hold for functions $f: \mathbb C \to \mathbb R$

Tags: complex-analysis, derivatives, complex-numbers

Given a function $f: \mathbb C \to \mathbb R$ ($z = x+yi, \; x,y \in \mathbb R)$

**Does this hold?**

> 1. $f$ has an extremum at $ z_0 = x_0 + iy_0$
> 2. $f$ is differentiable at $S$ and $z_0 \in S$
>
> Then $f' (z_0) = 0$ which suggests $$\frac {\partial f}{\partial x}
>  \bigg | _{x= x_0} =\frac {\partial f}{\partial y} \bigg | _{y= y_0} =
> 0  $$

Comment: "A function such that..." ...such that  **what** ?!

Comment: Made an edit. Just wanted to denote z = x+iy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $f$ is real-valued the word "differentiable" can only mean "differentiable as a function $f:\>{\mathbb R}^2\to{\mathbb R}$", whether you prefer to write the points in ${\mathbb R}^2$ as pairs $(x,y)$ of real numbers or als complex numbers $z=x+iy$. In any case, if $f$ is locally extremal at the interior point $(x_0,y_0)$, resp. $z_0=x_0+iy_0$, of ${\rm dom}(f)$ then
$$f_x(x_0,y_0)=0\quad\wedge\quad f_y(x_0,y_0)=0\ .$$
Note that for such a function the formula $f'(z_0)=0$ makes no sense since $f'(z_0)$ has no meaning as a real or complex number in this context. What is defined, however, is the differential $$df(x_0,y_0)=f_x(x_0,y_0) dx+f_y(x_0,y_0)dy\ ,$$
resp. the gradient vector $\nabla f(x_0,y_0)$ representing this differential via the scalar product.

Comment: Thank you very intuitive! The function I wanted to apply this thm finally reduced to a real valued function f(x,y)